# Нужно вывести на экран массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужно вывести на экран массив и символ, который встречается  больше всего в нём.

Мой код:

```
int main()
{
  const int max_elem = 200000;
  char *array1 = new char(max_elem);
  for (int i = 0; i < max_elem; ++i)
  {
    array1[i] = rand() % 200;
  }
  std::cout << "array -" << array1 << '\n';

  size_t size = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);
   char  find = findCharacter(array1, size);
  std::cout << "find -" << find << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Но не выводится. Что я не так  делаю?

`findCharacter` функция, где я ищу символ. Она правильно работает.

Comment: "вывести на екран масив" - мы ожидаем увидеть цикл, ну на крайний случай вызов в специализированую либу которая умеет вывести цикл на экран. этого нету. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: чтобы вывести массив на екран нужно хорошо пошаманить с бубном

Comment: @nick_n_a а что это по вашему? for (int i = 0; i < max_elem; ++i)
  {
    array1[i] = rand() % 200;
  }
  std::cout << "array -" << array1 << '\n';

Comment: Ну... с++ не умеет так выводить. Прийдётся вам  `std::cout <<  array1[i]` писать, предварительно обвернув в цикл. Вы переоцениваете возможности с++

Comment: @nick_n_a да я в енс в фор и теперь норм выводится. Спасибо

Comment: Я всётаки тоже не досмотрел, с++ умеет так выводить массив char как строку, но... есть понятие ASCII-z, т.е. последний елемент массива должен быть ноль `'\0'`. С ASCII-z больше мороки (для новичка) плюс "служебные символы", возможно циклом будет лучше (проще).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В продемонстрированном куске кода несколько ошибок:

1. Попытка вывести на экран массив случайных символов как строку до добра не доведёт. Во-первых, могут быть нулевые символы, которые просто приведут к остановке дальнейшего вывода (см. нуль-терминированные строки). Во-вторых, имеются непечатные символы, типа перевода строк, звоночков и т.п. Чтобы все эти проблемы решить, надо выводить в нормальном цикле посимвольно, примерно так же как заполняете, и учитывая значение этих символов. Самый простой способ, выводить символ числом, т.е. привести перед выводом к `int`.
2. `sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]);` такой подход к определению размера массива актуален только для массивов, размер которых задаётся на этапе компиляции, и уж точно не через `new`, а вида `T arr[N]`. К тому же совсем не понятно, зачем пытаться вообще вычислить этот размер, если он задан заранее через переменную `max_elem`.